# mysql JOIN not working how I think it should

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can someone please explain why the following query is returning 5 copies of each row? What have I done wrong?:

```
(
SELECT user_id, act_id, act_date, act_score, users.posts_check,  'act' AS 
'type' FROM actsWithScore
JOIN users
WHERE user_id
IN ( 1, 5 )
)
UNION ALL (

SELECT user_voter, act_id, vote_date, vote_score, users.posts_check,  'vote' AS 
TYPE FROM votes
JOIN users
WHERE user_voter
IN ( 1, 5 )
)
LIMIT 0 , 50
```

I am getting the following result:

```
user_id act_id  act_date            act_score   posts_check         TYPE
1       1       2014-02-05 05:25:25     NULL    2014-03-13 06:52:51  act
1       1       2014-02-05 05:25:25     NULL    0000-00-00 00:00:00  act
1       1       2014-02-05 05:25:25     NULL    0000-00-00 00:00:00  act
1       1       2014-02-05 05:25:25     NULL    0000-00-00 00:00:00  act
1       1       2014-02-05 05:25:25     NULL    0000-00-00 00:00:00  act
1       2       2014-02-05 05:28:16     1       2014-03-13 06:52:51  act
1       2       2014-02-05 05:28:16     1       0000-00-00 00:00:00  act
1       2       2014-02-05 05:28:16     1       0000-00-00 00:00:00  act
1       2       2014-02-05 05:28:16     1       0000-00-00 00:00:00  act
1       2       2014-02-05 05:28:16     1       0000-00-00 00:00:00  act
```

Rows `0` and `5` are correct but not sure why they are duplicating?

Comment: why not normal join with ON clause?

Comment: Update question with table content or create a SQL Fiddle, which will help to give a proper answer.

Comment: Answer below worked. Why the hell the downvote? I've never had to use a `JOIN` before so needed some legitimate help. I provided plenty of info. If Madhivanan could get it, why couldn't you? maybe you should give yourself the downvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to join the tables. It should be

```
(
SELECT user_id, act_id, act_date, act_score, users.posts_check,  'act' AS 
'type' FROM actsWithScore
JOIN users on actsWithScore.user_id=users.user_id
WHERE user_id
IN ( 1, 5 )
)
UNION ALL (

SELECT user_voter, act_id, vote_date, vote_score, users.posts_check,  'vote' AS 
TYPE FROM votes
JOIN users on votes.user_id=users.user_id
WHERE user_voter
IN ( 1, 5 )
)
LIMIT 0 , 50
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad you could help with an answer rather than a completely useless downvote!